# My url rewriting is not working | Mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do url_rewrite in webpage. Here are some codes

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^first_folder/second_folder/mobile-details/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ first_folder/second_folder/mobile-details.php?mpid=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my code from where the page will go to another page

```
  <a href="mobile-details/<?=$res['Name'];?>"> Some text </a>
```

Earlier the code was like this

```
    <a href="mobile-details.php?mpid=<?=$res['Name']; ?>"> Some text </a>
```

This is the code where the code will land.

```
if(isset($_GET['mpid']))
            {
                $pid=$_GET['mpid'];
                $result=$con->link->query("select * from database_name where Name='$pid'") or die($con->link->error);
                while($res=$result->fetch_assoc())
                {
```

This code doesn't work, simply lands to unavailable page.

Comment: Where is htaccess located?

Comment: Oh sorry! htaccess is outside first folder

Comment: I have already removed slash after Z in rewriterule